# Building Tensorflow with Bazel: Executing genrule //tensorflow:tensorflow_python_api_gen failed (Exit 1): bash failed: error executing command

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi3, bazel

I try to build TensorFlow source on Raspberry Pi 3, but got some build error. Did I miss to install any python module?

**The below is the ERROR log:**

```
ERROR: /home/pi/tf/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:581:1: Executing genrule //tensorflow:tensorflow_python_api_gen failed (Exit 1): bash failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games \
  /bin/bash -c 'source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api --root_init_template=tensorflow/api_template.__init__.py --apidir=bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow --apiname=tensorflow --apiversion=2 --package=tensorflow.python --output_package=tensorflow bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/app/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/bitwise/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/compat/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/data/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/debugging/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/distributions/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/distributions/bijectors/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/dtypes/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/errors/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/feature_column/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/gfile/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/graph_util/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/image/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/io/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/initializers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/activations/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/densenet/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/inception_resnet_v2/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/inception_v3/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/mobilenet/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/nasnet/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/resnet50/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/vgg16/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/vgg19/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/xception/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/backend/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/callbacks/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/constraints/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/boston_housing/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/cifar10/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/cifar100/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/imdb/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/mnist/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/reuters/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/estimator/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/initializers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/layers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/losses/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/metrics/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/models/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/optimizers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/image/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/sequence/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/text/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/regularizers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/utils/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/wrappers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/layers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/linalg/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/logging/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/losses/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/manip/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/math/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/metrics/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/nn/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/nn/rnn_cell/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/profiler/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/python_io/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/quantization/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/resource_loader/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/strings/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/builder/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/constants/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/loader/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/main_op/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/signature_constants/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/signature_def_utils/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/tag_constants/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/utils/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/sets/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/sparse/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/spectral/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/summary/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/sysconfig/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/test/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/train/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/train/queue_runner/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/user_ops/__init__.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow9ConcatCPUINS_8bfloat16EEEvPNS_10DeviceBaseERKSt6vectorISt10unique_ptrINS_6TTypesIT_Li2EiE11ConstMatrixESt14default_deleteIS9_EESaISC_EEPNS8_6MatrixE
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools.api.generator import doc_srcs
  File "/home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/pi/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pi/f3a4f5c6bcc63d5d3ef13daa2fa0a18d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow9ConcatCPUINS_8bfloat16EEEvPNS_10DeviceBaseERKSt6vectorISt10unique_ptrINS_6TTypesIT_Li2EiE11ConstMatrixESt14default_deleteIS9_EESaISC_EEPNS8_6MatrixE


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 38200.263s, Critical Path: 2622.26s
INFO: 2455 processes: 2455 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
=================================================================================
```

**The below is my build environment**

1. build command

   ```
   bazel build -c opt --copt="-mfpu=neon-vfpv4" --copt="-funsafe-math-optimizations" --copt="-ftree-vectorize" --copt="-fomit-frame-pointer" --local_resources 1024,1.0,1.0 --verbose_failures tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
   ```
2. gcc version

   ```
   pi@raspberrypi:~/tf/tensorflow/tensorflow $ gcc -v
   Using built-in specs.
   COLLECT_GCC=gcc
   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/lto-wrapper
   Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
   Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Raspbian 4.8.5-4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-armhf/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-armhf --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-armhf --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
   Thread model: posix
   gcc version 4.8.5 (Raspbian 4.8.5-4)
   ```
3. github document: https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md